# jQuery window resize show button

Tags: jquery, html, ruby, erb

I've made a simple jQuery function where when the window gets resized to less than 1000, a button with class `navbar-toggle` gets shown, and an unordered list with class `navbar-nav` gets hidden (this is the navigation).

Problem is, when the button gets shown and the navbar gets hidden, the button doesn't actually function as it should - to provide a dropdown list. Just need help to make this button actually function as it should

jQuery function:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
        $(".navbar-toggle").show();
        $(".navbar-nav").hide();
    } else {
        // do nothing
    }
});
```

HTML/ERB:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">   
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost:3000">Buy &amp; Sell</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><%= link_to "All Items", root_path %></li>
                <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
                    <li><%= link_to category.name, items_path(category: category.name) %></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><%= link_to "New Item", new_item_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Account", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
            </ul>
            <% else %>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path   %></li>
            </ul>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried other ways? I.e. CSS, applying `display: none` and `display: block` to the relative elements instead

Comment: Yes have tried, although produces same result - button not working, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap. There are two steps: 1) Using the standard Bootstrap syntax for for navbars and 2) Setting the mobile menu breakpoint to 1000px.

### 1) Use the standard Bootstrap syntax for navbars

First, simply [adapt your code to fit the example in the Components: Navbar section](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass).

In your case, that would be:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">   
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navHeaderCollapse" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost:3000">Buy &amp; Sell</a>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navHeaderCollapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><%= link_to "All Items", root_path %></li>
            <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
            <li><%= link_to category.name, items_path(category: category.name) %></li>
         <% end %>
        </ul>

        <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><%= link_to "New Item", new_item_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Account", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
        </ul>

        <% else %>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Log In", new_user_session_path   %></li>
        </ul>
        <% end %>

    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

You **do not** need the custom jQuery code! Bootstrap will automatically handle the toggling of the mobile menu for you!

### 2) Set the mobile menu breakpoint to 1000px

Bootstrap allows you to modify the mobile navbar breakpoint:

> #### Changing the collapsed mobile navbar breakpoint
>
> The navbar collapses into its vertical mobile view when the viewport is narrower than $grid-float-breakpoint, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least $grid-float-breakpoint in width. Adjust this variable in the Sass source to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value is 768px (the smallest "small" or "tablet" screen). This variable is defined in _variables.scss of Bootstrap and then used in _navbar.scss.

If you are using the [twbs/bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) gem, it is very easy to override the `$grid-float-breakpoint` variable:

> You can override variables by simply redefining a variable before the @import directive.

In your case:

```
// File: app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

// Point at which the navbar becomes uncollapsed
$grid-float-breakpoint: 1001px;

// import bootstrap as usual
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: Thanks, although the reason i'm using the jQuery is because in the navbar, when the window is resized, some of the navigation links move underneath each other causing the mobile menu not to kick in until the window width is less than 1000.

Comment: You can adjust the point at which the menu "collapses" into the mobile menu:

The navbar collapses into its vertical mobile view when the viewport is narrower than $grid-float-breakpoint, and expands into its horizontal non-mobile view when the viewport is at least $grid-float-breakpoint in width. Adjust this variable in the Sass source to control when the navbar collapses/expands. The default value is 768px (the smallest "small" or "tablet" screen).

This variable is defined in _variables.scss of Bootstrap and then used in _navbar.scss. How are you loading Bootstrap? Maybe I can help...

Comment: Im loading bootstrap through a ruby gem so I dont actually have any of those scss files. Is there any way I can adjust the $grid-float-breakpoint value?

Comment: Dont worry actually, I just manually downloaded bootstrap and changed the grid-float-breakpoint value to 1000px. Then just copied across some files into the vendor folder and required them. Now its working! thanks for the help

Comment: Great job, Luka! I've also updated my answer on how to do it with the [twbs/bootstrap-sass gem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) in case you do want to continue using the gem (or other people who have the same problem do). Hope that it is the gem you're using (and not [twbs/bootstrap-rubygem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem)). If the latter, let me know, I am also happy to help with that one.